# FileNotFoundException why trying to open an image

Tags: c#, image, filenotfoundexception

I have an image in one of my project folders:
Lets say its in: 
`~/App_Themes/Default/images/SomeImage.png`

I want to load this image into a System.Drawing.Image, how do I do that?

If I try using the FromFile method of the Image class:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile("~/App_Themes/Default/images/SomeImage.png", true);
```

I get a `FileNotFoundException`.

I have read some suggesting to store the image into the Server but that's not an option. Is there any way to load this into the Image?

Comment: Are you using MVC or classic asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a relative path instead of a file path to locate the image. Try this:

```
var path = @"~/App_Themes/Default/images/SomeImage.png";

using (Image img = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(path)))
{
   do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it didn't work, I still get the same FileNotFoundException exception.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you try removing the `~` from the path in rboarman's example?

Comment: Yes I tried but it still doesn't work. I still get the exception.

Comment: Worked fine in my own project. You must have something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The problem for me was that I accidentally added Image folder inside of App_Code folder. I did not updated the code accordingly and therefore I was getting exception.

As soon I removed the Image folder out of App_Code folder, the problem was resolved.
Of course I could have updated also the path in the code.